# How to use SpiderMonkey's debugging support in the Mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, debugging, mongodb, spidermonkey, mongo-shell

MongoDB's shell extends SpiderMonkey. Is there a way to hook into some of [SpiderMonkey's debugging support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/JS_Debugger_API_Reference/Debugger)? I haven't been able to find a way to do even simple things like activate an onerror() handler to print call stack traces on unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Support for debugger objects was landed only a few months ago, so if the embedded SpiderMonkey version isn't reasonably up-to-date the in-shell debugger support may not even be present -- can you do a simple test to see if it's present, like evaluate |Debugger|? My recent shell gives |function Debugger() {[native code]}| as a result.

Comment: @cdleary `Debugger` is not defined so you are probably right: they haven't integrated these changes yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @cdleary's point, it looks like MongoDB's shell has not integrated SpiderMonkey's debugging support.

Answer (score 1):

Currently mongo's sources use spidermonkey 1.7, so there is no support for debugging API since it was added to 1.8 it seems.

In the future mongo may get upgraded to SM1.8, please file a ticket on jira.mongodb.org if you'd like to request features.